# How to set up Istio or Linkerd with namespace-level permissions (without cluster administration permission)?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, istio, linkerd

We are using a K8s cluster but we don't have cluster level permissions, so we can only create `Role` and `ServiceAccount` on our namespaces and we need install a service mesh solution (Istio or Linkerd) only in our namespaces.

Our operation team will agree to apply CRDs on the cluster for us, so that part is taken care of, but we can’t request for cluster admin permissions to set up the service mesh solutions.

We think that it should be possible to do this if we change all the `ClusterRole`s and `ClusterRoleBinding`s to `Role`s and `RoleBinding`s on Helm charts.

So, the question is: how can we set up a service mesh using Istio or Linkerd without having admin permission on the K8s cluster?

Answer (score 4):

Linkerd cannot function without certain ClusterRoles, ClusterRoleBindings, etc. However, it does provide a two-stage install mode where one phase corresponds to "cluster admin permissions needed" (aka give this to your ops team) and the other "cluster admin permissions NOT needed" (do this part yourself).

The set of cluster admin permissions needed is scoped down to be as small as possible, and can be inspected (The `linkerd install config` command simply outputs it to stdout.)

See https://linkerd.io/2/tasks/install/#multi-stage-install for details.

For context, we originally tried to have a mode that required no cluster-level privileges, but it became clear we were going against the grain with how K8s operates, and we ended up abandoning that approach in favor of making the control plane cluster-wide but multi-tenant.